# working with webstorage to apply themes

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am trying to implement multiple themes support in my application on basis of button click, and applying it on window load.

**Here is my jQuery-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {
                //set the value to the text fields
                $("ul#color-schemes li a").click(function () {
                    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
                    return localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('class'));
                });
                $(window).on('load', function () {
                    localStorage.setItem($('body'), $('body').addClass('darkgrey-scheme'));
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I have stored class in this case - `darkgray-scheme` and then trying to apply it on window load on body. But this doesn't apply it on body and also it doesn't return me that `dark-gray` class while setting item with storage.

How this should be done?

Comment: When do you want the theme to apply? If the user selects a theme from the ul-li, do you want to load the page again?

Comment: @shaunakde, This theme is already being applied on ul li click, but I want it to remain after window reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/P63Cb/2/)**.

**Part I :**

```
$("ul#color-schemes li a").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
    localStorage.setItem('class',$(this).attr('class'));  //set the class value
    $('body').removeAttr('class');
    $('body').addClass(localStorage.getItem('class'));
});
```

**Part II:**

```
$('body').addClass(localStorage.getItem('class'));    //get the class value
```

---

In your project just include **Part I** in document ready - `$(function () {});`
and **Part II** in `$(window).on('load', function () {});` or both in document ready.

So your final function would be like :

```
$(function () {
    $("ul#color-schemes li a").click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        localStorage.setItem('class',$(this).attr('class'));  //set the class value
        $('body').removeAttr('class');
        $('body').addClass(localStorage.getItem('class'));
    });

    $('body').addClass(localStorage.getItem('class'));    //get the class value
});
```

For localStorage and other webStorage uses  check this **[Page](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)**.